# Python code terminated in Pycharm with exit code 1073741819

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Python version: 3.4

Hi, I was running a small Python code in Pycharm, but it was terminated with the exit code 1073741819.

I've tried the same code in the Python command line and Anaconda, and both worked. Any idea why Pycharm has the problem, and how can I get it work in Pycharm? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Search web for 'pycharm exit code 1073741819' and peruse the answers.  You are not the first to see this ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Its too late to answer now, but maybe it helps someone else. My code also worked right with command line but not inside pycharm, it usually happens when we switch between different projects on PyCharm.

I fixed it by:

1- Restarting the Pycharm and reloading the project into it.

2- Clearing the heap memory by clicking at this in status bar:
[image]

and now it works pretty fine.

P.S: If this indicator doesnt appear then visibility of this section in the Status bar is defined by the **Show memory indicator** check box in the **Appearance** page of the **Settings/Preferences** dialog. It is not shown by default.

Comment: You should also explain how to enable this heap indicator in the status bar